# connect to mysql database with wps

Tags: sas

I am working with the statistician at my company and trying to connect to a mysql database from WPS (world programming system).  The WPS docs are pretty terrible.

i tried this sas/access approach:

```
proc sql;
    connect to mysql (user=testuser password=testpass server=mysqlserv database=mysqldb port=3306
    execute (create table whotookorders as
      select ordernum, takenby,
        from orders, employees
        where orders.takenby=employees.empid)
      by mysql
quit;
```

however, i got the error:

> could not load module MYSQL or one of it's dependencies.  etc. etc.

Is there something specific configuration wise that you have to do to use MYSQL with WPS?

Comment: Are you sure you have the MySQL module installed?  At least for SAS, each RDBMS module is separate, unless you use OLEDB or ODBC anyway, so if you didn't install it initially it's not there.  `proc setinit;run;` may be helpful, if WPS uses the same style as SAS to manage things.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to fix this, here was my solution in Linux and how I found it.

The mysql engine is the following module: "libwpsemsql.so" To see what was missing you can type:

- ldd /yourfolder/wpl/wps-3.3/bin/libwpsemsql.so

You will noticed unresolved link entries. Define a LD_LIBRARY_PATH as follows and put it in your profile or in /etc/profile.d/wps.sh as an example.

- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/yourfolder/wpl/wps-3.3/bin

Next you will see the missing so is actually libmysql.so.16. I have no idea where they picked this up from originally but I found a working copy from https://github.com/janzhou/js-c that works by typing the following:

- change into your wps installation folder
- cd /yourfolder/wps-3.3/bin
- wget https://github.com/janzhou/js-c/raw/master/mysql/linux-x86-64bit/lib/libmysql.so.16.0.0
- ln -s libmysql.so.16.0.0 libmysql.so.16

That should be it! This is a useful technique for digging into any missing dependancy as well. In windows you can look at your wps installation folder and find the WPS Workbench user guide on page #174 titled "Connecting to a MySQL database" and it references how to download the Connector/C and install in windows. I tried this same technique in Linux but it resulted in a libmysqlclient.so.18.6 and when I tried to use it, wps segment faulted.